# How to apply two way binding to kendo controls generated using Javascript? KendoUI generates duplicate input fields, hiding the main one

Tags: javascript, angular, kendo-ui, kendo-ui-angular2

I'm trying on my ASP.NET MVC app with Angular 4.
I've been also using Kendo UI.

My control in html look like:

```
<div class="editor-field">
   <input id="control-xyz-id" class="form-control" type="text" [(ngModel)]="randomValue">
</div>
```

Then in my Javascript file I simply create Kendo control, ex. NumericTextBox

```
$("#control-xyz-id").kendoNumericTextBox();
```

This gives me a nice looking control with spinners and formatting.

I'm trying to apply two-way data binding. However the problem is that it doesn't work with Kendo, because it creates another input control that accepts the value, but the main one is hidden.
The below html is generated. As you can see, my main control

```
<input type="text" class="k-formatted-value form-control ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid k-input" tabindex="0" title="" aria-disabled="false" aria-readonly="false" style="display: inline-block;">
<input class="form-control ng-pristine ng-valid k-input ng-touched" id="control-xyz-id" style="display: none;" type="text" data-role="numerictextbox" role="spinbutton" aria-valuenow="" aria-disabled="false" aria-readonly="false">
```

Without conversion to Kendo NumericTextBox, the binding works fine.

Does any one know any simple way to do a work around for this?
I use kendo datetime pickers, dropdowns/comboboxes, etc.

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: just out of curiosity. why not use standart angular 2 controls? Why not <kendo-numerictextbox></kendo-numerictextbox>?

Comment: You can also check out the suggested component's forms support documentation:

https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/inputs/numerictextbox/forms/


Two-way value binding can be also achieved via the value property, e.g.:

<kendo-numerictextbox [(value)]="value"...

Comment: I have tried using using <kendo-numerictextbox> and having the following issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48230196/kendo-ui-creates-a-double-input-when-added-to-angular-4-app